# springboot, spring boot jpa,class not found exception, Endpointer

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, classnotfoundexception

**BlogController: **

```
package com.taskproject.blogproject.controller;

import com.taskproject.blogproject.entities.Blog;
import com.taskproject.blogproject.repositories.BlogRepository;

import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;


import java.util.List;

@RestController
@Service
@RequestMapping("/blogs")
public class BlogController {
    private final BlogRepository blogRepository;

    public BlogController(BlogRepository blogRepository) {
        this.blogRepository = blogRepository;
    }


    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Blog> createBlog(@RequestBody Blog blog) {
        Blog savedBlog = blogRepository.save(blog);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(savedBlog);
    }

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<Blog>> getAllBlogs() {
        List<Blog> blogs = blogRepository.findAll();
        return ResponseEntity.ok(blogs);
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Blog> getBlogById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return blogRepository.findById(id)
                .map(ResponseEntity::ok)
                .orElse(ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
    }

    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Blog> updateBlog(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody Blog updatedBlog) {
        return blogRepository.findById(id)
                .map(blog -> {
                    blog.setTitle(updatedBlog.getTitle());
                    blog.setDescription(updatedBlog.getDescription());
                    Blog savedBlog = blogRepository.save(blog);
                    return ResponseEntity.ok(savedBlog);
                })
                .orElse(ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> deleteBlog(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return blogRepository.findById(id)
                .map(blog -> {
                    blogRepository.delete(blog);
                    return ResponseEntity.ok().<Void>build();
                })
                .orElse(ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
    }
}
```

Pom xml :

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 [https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"\>](https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd%22%5C%3E)     <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>     <parent>         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>         <version>3.2.3</version>         <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->     </parent>     <groupId>com.taskproject</groupId>     <artifactId>BlogProject</artifactId>     <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>     <name>BlogProject</name>     <description>BlogProject</description>     <properties>         <java.version>17</java.version>     </properties>     <dependencies>         <dependency>             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>             <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>         </dependency>         <dependency>             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>             <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>         </dependency>         <dependency>             <artifactId>h2</artifactId>             <scope>runtime</scope>         </dependency>         <dependency>             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>             <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>             <scope>test</scope>         </dependency>     </dependencies>      <build>         <plugins>             <plugin>                 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>                 <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>             </plugin>         </plugins>     </build>  </project>

Application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/blogs
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=p@sssw0rd
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.taskproject.blogproject

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect


server.port=8080


spring.security.user.name=admin
spring.security.user.password=adminpassword
```

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.taskproject.blogproject
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:534)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:513)
at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:304)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.driverClassIsLoadable(DataSourceProperties.java:194)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.determineDriverClassName(DataSourceProperties.java:175)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.PropertiesJdbcConnectionDetails.getDriverClassName(PropertiesJdbcConnectionDetails.java:49)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration.createDataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:55)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.dataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:117)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:140)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:647)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:639)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1335)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1165)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1443)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:907)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:785)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:542)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1335)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1165)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1231)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:949)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343)
at com.taskproject.blogproject.BlogProjectApplication.main(BlogProjectApplication.java:10)

Comment: what's in `BlogProjectApplication ` file?

Answer (score 0):

in Application.properties change

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.taskproject.blogproject
```

to

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```